# Como trocar o icon do font awesome com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Por que a classe do menu icon não troca de `fa-caret-right` para `fa-caret-down` quando eu passo o mouse sobre o meu botão?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Template Model</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-HK5fgLBL+xu6dm/Ii3z4xhlSUyZgTT9tuc/hSrtw6uzJOvgRr2a9jyxxT1ely+B+xFAmJKVSTbpM/CuL7qxO8w==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ballet&family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <header class="header">
        <nav class="nav">
          <a class="logo" href="">LOGO</a>
          <div class="burger">
            <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="menu">
            <a class="menu__item" href="">Produtos</a>
            <a class="menu__item" href="">Clientes</a>
            <a class="menu__item" href="">Pedidos</a>
            <a class="menu__item" href="">Investimentos</a>
            <div class="dropdown">
              <div class="dropdown__btn">
                <span>Relatórios</span>
                <i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="dropdown__content">
                <a class="dropdown__item" href="">Clientes</a>
                <a class="dropdown__item" href="">Pedidos</a>
                <a class="dropdown__item" href="">Investimentos</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <a class="menu__item" href="">Sair</a>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </header>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/js/all.min.js" integrity="sha512-UwcC/iaz5ziHX7V6LjSKaXgCuRRqbTp1QHpbOJ4l1nw2/boCfZ2KlFIqBUA/uRVF0onbREnY9do8rM/uT/ilqw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/script.js' %}"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/* VARIABLES */
:root {
    --base-1: #f4f4f4;
    --color-1: #633517;
}

/* RESET */
* {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul,
li {
    list-style: none;
}

img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

html {
    background: var(--base-1);
}

/* STYLE */

.container {
    width: 1140px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
    .container {
        width: 960px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
    .container {
        width: 720px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 786px) {
    .container {
        width: 540px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 576px) {
    .container {
        width: 100%;
    }
}


.header {
    border-bottom: 2px solid var(--color-1);
}

.nav {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.logo {
    font-family: 'Ballet', cursive;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: var(--color-1);
    flex-basis: 250px;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
}

.logo:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
}

.burger {
    color:var(--color-1);
    transform: scale(2);
    display: none;
}

.burger:hover {
    transform: scale(2.1);
}

.menu {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.menu__item {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: var(--color-1);
}

.menu__item:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
}

.menu > .menu__item {
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.menu > .menu__item:last-child {
    margin-left: auto;
    font-size: 12px;
    display: none;
}

.dropdown {
    margin-left: 20px;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown__btn {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    color: var(--color-1);
}

.dropdown__btn > span {
    font-size: 18px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

.dropdown__btn:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
}

.dropdown__content {
    position: absolute;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px var(--color-1);
    border-radius: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: var(--base-1);
    margin-left: -30px;
    display: none;
}


.dropdown__item {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: var(--color-1);
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.dropdown__item:hover {
    color: var(--base-1);
    background: var(--color-1);
}

.dropdown:hover > .dropdown__content {
    display: block;
}
```

JS:

```js
const dropdown = document.querySelector('.dropdown')
const dropdown__btn_I = document.querySelector('.dropdown__btn i');

dropdown.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    dropdown__btn_I.classList.toggle('fa-caret-right');
    dropdown__btn_I.classList.toggle('fa-caret-down');
    console.log(dropdown__btn_I);
});

dropdown.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
    dropdown__btn_I.classList.toggle('fa-caret-right');
    dropdown__btn_I.classList.toggle('fa-caret-down');
    console.log(dropdown__btn_I);
});
```

Imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O código que voce informou parece está funcionando normalmente. [Veja aqui.](https://codepen.io/cmte-cardeal/pen/ExNXoeV)

Comment: Aqui não funciona. Tipo visualmente não acontece nada, mas dando um console.log no seletor  dropdown_btn_I ele é alterado. Eu vou colocar outra imagem com a saida também.

Comment: Coloque mais códigos. O problema pode estar em outro luga...

Comment: Pronto! Isso é tudo da parte do `header`

Comment: obs: Eu estou usando o django.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por algum motivo, este problema está sendo causado pelo script do *Font Awesome*. Ele está comentando a linha onde está o icone `i` e colocando um SVG no lugar.

Veja:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja o código não funcionando:

<sub>Removi os links não relevantes para facilitar a visualização.</sub>

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Template Model</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css"
      integrity="sha512-HK5fgLBL+xu6dm/Ii3z4xhlSUyZgTT9tuc/hSrtw6uzJOvgRr2a9jyxxT1ely+B+xFAmJKVSTbpM/CuL7qxO8w=="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ballet&family=Poppins&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <style>
      /* VARIABLES */
      :root {
        --base-1: #f4f4f4;
        --color-1: #633517;
      }

      /* RESET */
      * {
        font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: 400;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }

      a {
        text-decoration: none;
      }

      ul,
      li {
        list-style: none;
      }

      img {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
      }

      html {
        background: var(--base-1);
      }

      /* STYLE */

      .container {
        width: 1140px;
        margin: 0 auto;
      }

      @media (max-width: 1200px) {
        .container {
          width: 960px;
        }
      }

      @media (max-width: 992px) {
        .container {
          width: 720px;
        }
      }

      @media (max-width: 786px) {
        .container {
          width: 540px;
        }
      }

      @media (max-width: 576px) {
        .container {
          width: 100%;
        }
      }

      .header {
        border-bottom: 2px solid var(--color-1);
      }

      .nav {
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
      }

      .logo {
        font-family: 'Ballet', cursive;
        font-size: 24px;
        color: var(--color-1);
        flex-basis: 250px;
        letter-spacing: 5px;
      }

      .logo:hover {
        transform: scale(1.1);
      }

      .burger {
        color: var(--color-1);
        transform: scale(2);
        display: none;
      }

      .burger:hover {
        transform: scale(2.1);
      }

      .menu {
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
      }

      .menu__item {
        font-size: 18px;
        color: var(--color-1);
      }

      .menu__item:hover {
        transform: scale(1.1);
      }

      .menu > .menu__item {
        margin-left: 20px;
      }

      .menu > .menu__item:last-child {
        margin-left: auto;
        font-size: 12px;
        display: none;
      }

      .dropdown {
        margin-left: 20px;
        position: relative;
        cursor: pointer;
      }

      .dropdown__btn {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        color: var(--color-1);
      }

      .dropdown__btn > span {
        font-size: 18px;
        padding-right: 5px;
      }

      .dropdown__btn:hover {
        transform: scale(1.1);
      }

      .dropdown__content {
        position: absolute;
        box-shadow: 0 0 3px var(--color-1);
        border-radius: 5px;
        overflow: hidden;
        background: var(--base-1);
        margin-left: -30px;
        display: none;
      }

      .dropdown__item {
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 18px;
        color: var(--color-1);
        padding: 10px 20px;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
      }

      .dropdown__item:hover {
        color: var(--base-1);
        background: var(--color-1);
      }

      .dropdown:hover > .dropdown__content {
        display: block;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <header class="header">
        <nav class="nav">
          <a class="logo" href="">LOGO</a>
          <div class="burger">
            <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="menu">
             <div class="dropdown">
              <div class="dropdown__btn teste">
                <span>Relatórios</span>
                <i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="dropdown__content">
                <a class="dropdown__item" href="">Clientes</a>
                <a class="dropdown__item" href="">Pedidos</a>
                <a class="dropdown__item" href="">Investimentos</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <a class="menu__item" href="">Sair</a>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </header>
    </div>
    <script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/js/all.min.js"
      integrity="sha512-UwcC/iaz5ziHX7V6LjSKaXgCuRRqbTp1QHpbOJ4l1nw2/boCfZ2KlFIqBUA/uRVF0onbREnY9do8rM/uT/ilqw=="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script>
      const dropdown = document.querySelector('.dropdown');
      const dropdown__btn_I = document.querySelector('.dropdown__btn i');

      dropdown.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
        dropdown__btn_I.classList.toggle('fa-caret-right');
        dropdown__btn_I.classList.toggle('fa-caret-down');
        // console.log(dropdown__btn_I);
      });

      dropdown.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
        dropdown__btn_I.classList.toggle('fa-caret-right');
        dropdown__btn_I.classList.toggle('fa-caret-down');
        // console.log(dropdown__btn_I);
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Agora, eu comentei o script do *Font Awesome*, funcionou como o esperado:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Template Model</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css"
      integrity="sha512-HK5fgLBL+xu6dm/Ii3z4xhlSUyZgTT9tuc/hSrtw6uzJOvgRr2a9jyxxT1ely+B+xFAmJKVSTbpM/CuL7qxO8w=="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ballet&family=Poppins&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <style>
      /* VARIABLES */
      :root {
        --base-1: #f4f4f4;
        --color-1: #633517;
      }

      /* RESET */
      * {
        font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: 400;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }

      a {
        text-decoration: none;
      }

      ul,
      li {
        list-style: none;
      }

      img {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
      }

      html {
        background: var(--base-1);
      }

      /* STYLE */

      .container {
        width: 1140px;
        margin: 0 auto;
      }

      @media (max-width: 1200px) {
        .container {
          width: 960px;
        }
      }

      @media (max-width: 992px) {
        .container {
          width: 720px;
        }
      }

      @media (max-width: 786px) {
        .container {
          width: 540px;
        }
      }

      @media (max-width: 576px) {
        .container {
          width: 100%;
        }
      }

      .header {
        border-bottom: 2px solid var(--color-1);
      }

      .nav {
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
      }

      .logo {
        font-family: 'Ballet', cursive;
        font-size: 24px;
        color: var(--color-1);
        flex-basis: 250px;
        letter-spacing: 5px;
      }

      .logo:hover {
        transform: scale(1.1);
      }

      .burger {
        color: var(--color-1);
        transform: scale(2);
        display: none;
      }

      .burger:hover {
        transform: scale(2.1);
      }

      .menu {
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
      }

      .menu__item {
        font-size: 18px;
        color: var(--color-1);
      }

      .menu__item:hover {
        transform: scale(1.1);
      }

      .menu > .menu__item {
        margin-left: 20px;
      }

      .menu > .menu__item:last-child {
        margin-left: auto;
        font-size: 12px;
        display: none;
      }

      .dropdown {
        margin-left: 20px;
        position: relative;
        cursor: pointer;
      }

      .dropdown__btn {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        color: var(--color-1);
      }

      .dropdown__btn > span {
        font-size: 18px;
        padding-right: 5px;
      }

      .dropdown__btn:hover {
        transform: scale(1.1);
      }

      .dropdown__content {
        position: absolute;
        box-shadow: 0 0 3px var(--color-1);
        border-radius: 5px;
        overflow: hidden;
        background: var(--base-1);
        margin-left: -30px;
        display: none;
      }

      .dropdown__item {
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 18px;
        color: var(--color-1);
        padding: 10px 20px;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
      }

      .dropdown__item:hover {
        color: var(--base-1);
        background: var(--color-1);
      }

      .dropdown:hover > .dropdown__content {
        display: block;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <header class="header">
        <nav class="nav">
          <a class="logo" href="">LOGO</a>
          <div class="burger">
            <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="menu">
             <div class="dropdown">
              <div class="dropdown__btn teste">
                <span>Relatórios</span>
                <i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="dropdown__content">
                <a class="dropdown__item" href="">Clientes</a>
                <a class="dropdown__item" href="">Pedidos</a>
                <a class="dropdown__item" href="">Investimentos</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <a class="menu__item" href="">Sair</a>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </header>
    </div>
    <!-- <script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/js/all.min.js"
      integrity="sha512-UwcC/iaz5ziHX7V6LjSKaXgCuRRqbTp1QHpbOJ4l1nw2/boCfZ2KlFIqBUA/uRVF0onbREnY9do8rM/uT/ilqw=="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script> -->
    <script>
      const dropdown = document.querySelector('.dropdown');
      const dropdown__btn_I = document.querySelector('.dropdown__btn i');

      dropdown.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
        dropdown__btn_I.classList.toggle('fa-caret-right');
        dropdown__btn_I.classList.toggle('fa-caret-down');
        // console.log(dropdown__btn_I);
      });

      dropdown.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
        dropdown__btn_I.classList.toggle('fa-caret-right');
        dropdown__btn_I.classList.toggle('fa-caret-down');
        // console.log(dropdown__btn_I);
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Não posso garantir que essa é uma solução viável, apenas coloquei para provar e você perceber aonde está o problema. Vai depender do seu julgamento usar ou não esse script.

---

## OBS:

Quando usei um arquivo de script diferente do FA, resolveu o problema.

No caso de teste, eu usei o arquivo `fontawesome.min.js` no lugar da `all.min.js` e funcionou:

```
<script 
 src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/js/fontawesome.min.js" 
 integrity="sha512-pafh0hrrT9ZPZl/jx0cwyp7N2+ozgQf+YK94jSupHHLD2lcEYTLxEju4mW/2sbn4qFEfxJGZyIX/yJiQvgglpw==" 
 crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
```

Veja funcionando:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Template Model</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css"
      integrity="sha512-HK5fgLBL+xu6dm/Ii3z4xhlSUyZgTT9tuc/hSrtw6uzJOvgRr2a9jyxxT1ely+B+xFAmJKVSTbpM/CuL7qxO8w=="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ballet&family=Poppins&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <style>
      /* VARIABLES */
      :root {
        --base-1: #f4f4f4;
        --color-1: #633517;
      }

      /* RESET */
      * {
        font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: 400;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }

      a {
        text-decoration: none;
      }

      ul,
      li {
        list-style: none;
      }

      img {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
      }

      html {
        background: var(--base-1);
      }

      /* STYLE */

      .container {
        width: 1140px;
        margin: 0 auto;
      }

      @media (max-width: 1200px) {
        .container {
          width: 960px;
        }
      }

      @media (max-width: 992px) {
        .container {
          width: 720px;
        }
      }

      @media (max-width: 786px) {
        .container {
          width: 540px;
        }
      }

      @media (max-width: 576px) {
        .container {
          width: 100%;
        }
      }

      .header {
        border-bottom: 2px solid var(--color-1);
      }

      .nav {
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
      }

      .logo {
        font-family: 'Ballet', cursive;
        font-size: 24px;
        color: var(--color-1);
        flex-basis: 250px;
        letter-spacing: 5px;
      }

      .logo:hover {
        transform: scale(1.1);
      }

      .burger {
        color: var(--color-1);
        transform: scale(2);
        display: none;
      }

      .burger:hover {
        transform: scale(2.1);
      }

      .menu {
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
      }

      .menu__item {
        font-size: 18px;
        color: var(--color-1);
      }

      .menu__item:hover {
        transform: scale(1.1);
      }

      .menu > .menu__item {
        margin-left: 20px;
      }

      .menu > .menu__item:last-child {
        margin-left: auto;
        font-size: 12px;
        display: none;
      }

      .dropdown {
        margin-left: 20px;
        position: relative;
        cursor: pointer;
      }

      .dropdown__btn {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        color: var(--color-1);
      }

      .dropdown__btn > span {
        font-size: 18px;
        padding-right: 5px;
      }

      .dropdown__btn:hover {
        transform: scale(1.1);
      }

      .dropdown__content {
        position: absolute;
        box-shadow: 0 0 3px var(--color-1);
        border-radius: 5px;
        overflow: hidden;
        background: var(--base-1);
        margin-left: -30px;
        display: none;
      }

      .dropdown__item {
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 18px;
        color: var(--color-1);
        padding: 10px 20px;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
      }

      .dropdown__item:hover {
        color: var(--base-1);
        background: var(--color-1);
      }

      .dropdown:hover > .dropdown__content {
        display: block;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <header class="header">
        <nav class="nav">
          <a class="logo" href="">LOGO</a>
          <div class="burger">
            <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="menu">
             <div class="dropdown">
              <div class="dropdown__btn teste">
                <span>Relatórios</span>
                <i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="dropdown__content">
                <a class="dropdown__item" href="">Clientes</a>
                <a class="dropdown__item" href="">Pedidos</a>
                <a class="dropdown__item" href="">Investimentos</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <a class="menu__item" href="">Sair</a>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </header>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/js/fontawesome.min.js" integrity="sha512-pafh0hrrT9ZPZl/jx0cwyp7N2+ozgQf+YK94jSupHHLD2lcEYTLxEju4mW/2sbn4qFEfxJGZyIX/yJiQvgglpw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
      const dropdown = document.querySelector('.dropdown');
      const dropdown__btn_I = document.querySelector('.dropdown__btn i');

      dropdown.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
        dropdown__btn_I.classList.toggle('fa-caret-right');
        dropdown__btn_I.classList.toggle('fa-caret-down');
        // console.log(dropdown__btn_I);
      });

      dropdown.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
        dropdown__btn_I.classList.toggle('fa-caret-right');
        dropdown__btn_I.classList.toggle('fa-caret-down');
        // console.log(dropdown__btn_I);
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @danilomarto espera que vou informar mais uma coisa

Comment: Agora está funcionando direitunho. Muito obrigado pela ajuda!